# I can't see chatmessage_thread in my serializer result

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a small project using Django Rest Framework, I would like to access `chatmessage_thread`.  I don't see `chatmessage_thread` in my result, should I add something in my serializer ?

This is my queryset:

```
class ThreadViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = Thread.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ThreadSerializer


    def list(self, request):
        objectSerializer = self.serializer_class(Thread.objects.by_user(user=request.user).prefetch_related('chatmessage_thread').order_by('timestamp'), many=True)
        return Response(objectSerializer.data)
```

This is my serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from chat.models import Thread
from datetime import date

class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

**should I add something to my Serializer?**

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import Q

User = get_user_model()


class ThreadManager(models.Manager):
    def by_user(self, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.get('user')
        lookup = Q(first_person=user) | Q(second_person=user)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(lookup).distinct()
        return qs


class Thread(models.Model):
    first_person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='thread_first_person')
    second_person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
                                     related_name='thread_second_person')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = ThreadManager()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['first_person', 'second_person']


class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chatmessage_thread')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**I need help please**

Comment: Yes you need to add a serializer for `ChatMessage` and add that as a field to  `ThreadSerializer`

Comment: @bdbd  can you help me more please ( example )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to add a serializer for `ChatMessage` and add that as a field to `ThreadSerializer`. Something like this:

```
class ChatMessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChatMessage
        fields = '__all__'


class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chatmessage_thread = ChatMessageSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Comment: is there any way to hide password field :) ? from the serializer

Comment: I assume that's for `first_person` and `second_person`? I think in that case you need to manually define the `User` serializer for both those fields (and hide the password there) and not use `depth`.

Comment: can you just explain to me the steps without writing the code please, i got your idea, just i need more ( im new in django ) Thank you so so much in advance

Comment: Same thing with what we did for `ChatMessageSerializer`, this time write one for user. And define the person fields in your `ThreadSerializer` to use that serializer. Something like: `first_person = MyUserSerializer()`. Then inside `MyUserSerializer`, hide the password